# Rails: How to model a users that have many appointements with other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some issues conceptualizing my model: A User has 1:N appointements with other an other User. So I created a table Appointements and Users But for the join tables I end up having 2 user_id in the index this is wrong.

```
class AppointmentsUsersJointTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :appointments_users, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :appointment_id
    end

    add_index :appointments_users, :user_id
    add_index :appointments_users, :user_id
    add_index :appointments_users, :appointment_id
  end
end

#app/model/user.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Other details: A User can have up to two roles (`Rolify`) it's either a `:students` or `:mentor`. So a User that has the role (students) wants to take a courses with a User that has the role `:mentor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you need to name your columns different things. Perhaps `student_id` and `mentor_id`.

```
class AppointmentsUsersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :appointments_users, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :student_id
      t.integer :mentor_id
      t.integer :appointment_id
    end

    add_index :appointments_users, :student_id
    add_index :appointments_users, :mentor_id
    add_index :appointments_users, :appointment_id
  end
end
```

You'll need to specify those custom column names using the `foreign_key` option when you declare the association in your `User` class.

This setup will work only so long as your appointments involve two people. If there can be more than two, or if for your courses there should be one mentor and an arbitrary number of students, you'll need to set it up differently. It will probably also be beneficial to make `Mentor` and `Student` subclasses of `User` so you can distinguish them better. Here's one possible skeleton for that:

```
class User; end

class Mentor < User
  has_many :courses
  has_many :students, through: :courses
end

class Student < User
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, through: :enrollments
  has_many :mentors, through: :courses
end

class Course
  belongs_to :mentor
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :students, through: :enrollments
end

class Enrollment
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
end
```